# Append any special character after ever nth character without breaking word in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have query which returns over 100k rows in result set for eg.

```
  ID   Description 
   1   This site uses cookies to deliver our services and to show you relevantads and job listings. By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service. Your use of Stack Overflow’s Products and Services, including the Stack Overflow Network, is subject to these policies and term 
   2   RDBMS is the basis for SQL, and for all modern database systems such as MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, and Microsoft Access .The data in RDBMS is stored in database objects called tables. A table is a collection of related data entries and it consists of columns and rows.
    3  ................
    4  .............
    5
    and so on
```

I have used this function to add any special after nth position:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_BreakString (@STR VARCHAR(MAX), @CHARLEN INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NEW_STR VARCHAR(MAX), @POS INT, @LEN INT

    SET @NEW_STR = ''
    SET @POS = 1
    SET @LEN = LEN(@STR)

    WHILE @POS < @LEN
    BEGIN
        IF @POS = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @NEW_STR = SUBSTRING(@STR, @POS, @CHARLEN)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @NEW_STR = @NEW_STR + @#$ + SUBSTRING(@STR, @POS, @CHARLEN)
        END

        SET @POS = @POS + @CHARLEN
    END

    RETURN @NEW_STR
END
```

But I'm getting output like this:

```
select 
    id, dbo.fn_BreakString(description, 10) desc
from 
    tablea
```

Output:

```
ID   Description 
 1   This site u@#$ses cookie@#$s to deliver@#$our servi@#$ces and to show you @#$relevantads and job listings.including the Stack Overflow Network, is subject to these policies and term 
 2   RDBMS is t@#$he basis fo@#$r SQL, and @#$for all modern database systems such as MS SQL Server
 3  ................
 4  .............
 5
 and so on
```

I am trying append special after nth position without breaking word it can be before or after nth position it OK.

Desired output:

```
ID   Description 
 1   This site@#$uses cookies@#$ to deliver our@#$ services and to show you relevant ads and job listings. By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms
 2   RDBMS is@#$the basis@#$for SQL, and @#$for all modern database systems such as MS SQL Server
 3  ................
 4  .............
 5
 and so on
```

I have tried it below script sometime it work and sometime goes in infinite loop

```
DECLARE @NEW_STR NVARCHAR(MAX), @POS INT, @LEN INT, @End INT, @NEW_STRend NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @NEW_STR = ''
SET @POS=1
SET @LEN = LEN(@STR)

SELECT @LEN

WHILE @POS < @LEN
BEGIN
    IF @POS = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT @pos
        SET @End = LEN(LEFT(@Str, @CHARLEN)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Str, @CHARLEN)))

        PRINT @End
        SET @NEW_STR = SUBSTRING(@STR, @POS,@End )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @End = LEN(LEFT(@Str, @CHARLEN)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@Str, @CHARLEN)))
        PRINT @End

        SET @NEW_STR = @NEW_STR +@#$+ SUBSTRING(@STR, @POS+1,@End )
    END

    --select @pos ,@charlen
    SET @POS = @POS + @CHARLEN
END

SELECT @NEW_STR
```

Comment: Use [`charindex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find the next space after the 10 * _n*-th position and make you're replacement there.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find the index of the next space (' ') from the position you want to put your special characters, and then add your characters there.

```
DECLARE @nextPos INT

--then in your if & else
SET @nextPost = CHARINDEX(' ', @STR, @POS)

--then use that in place of @POS in your SUBSTRINGs
```

Comment: I have tried but some it work but some time it goes infinite loop

Comment: you  will need to revisit your end situation and this is a different problem now.  Also, why are you doing reverse of your string? I suggest you make a simple string, eg. "the quick brown" and set a value of, say, 4, and step through your current algorithm.

Comment: I am trying to first white space and append special characters and adding rest to string

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @STR nvarchar(max)='String to add special character',
 @CHARLEN int=5 --postion to add character
  DECLARE @NEW_STR nvarchar(max),
          @POS int,
          @LEN int
  SET @NEW_STR = ''
  SET @POS = 1
  SET @LEN = LEN(@STR)

WHILE LEN(@STR)>0
BEGIN   

    IF CHARINDEX(' ',@STR,@CHARLEN) >0 
    BEGIN

      SET @NEW_STR = @NEW_STR+'@!#'+SUBSTRING(@STR, 1, case when charindex(' ',@str,@CHARLEN)-1 <0 then len(@str)else charindex(' ',@str,@CHARLEN)-1 end )
      SELECT @STR= SUBSTRING(@STR,CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(@STR, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',@STR,@CHARLEN)))+1>LEN(@STR) THEN 1 ELSE LEN(SUBSTRING(@STR, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',@STR,@CHARLEN)))+1 END ,LEN(@STR))

    END
    ELSE IF CHARINDEX(' ',@STR,@CHARLEN) =0
    BEGIN

        SET @NEW_STR=@NEW_STR+SUBSTRING(@STR,1,LEN(@STR))
        --PRINT @NEW_STR
        SET @STR=''
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 

     SET @STR=''

    END 
end 
  select  @NEW_STR
```